# What is BVH and why is it slowing down my render so much?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation

I'm attempting to render a long character animation in cycles, and before each frame is starting to render, bvh is coming up and making everything super slow.

Comment: Well yes, but I'm trying to understand if there is an alternative to avoid the bvh loading every frame since it's slowing things down. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is part of path tracing. Every frame needs to be evaluated, but you can optimize your scene to render faster possibly. A search for optimizing cycles renders or similar should yield some results here.

Comment: ok great thank you!